# Searching through list of dictionary does not give reliable result?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Basically I have a list of dictionaries, generally each dictionary has less than 20 key:value pairs, and there are about 70,000 dictionaries in the list. The size of the list is about 360M bytes. Basically I want to find dictionaries that contains a specific keyword, make them a new list, and remove them from the old list. Here is my code:

```py
new_list = []

for item in old_list:
    if 'keyword' in item:
        new_list.append(item)
        old_list.remove(item)
```

What happened is that after the first run, I can still find dictionaries that contain 'keyword' in the old list. I run the same code for 2nd and 3rd time, each time the size of new_list grows and old_list shrinks.

It seems to be a very simple problem but I can not see why this happens. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You are changing `old_list` while you are iterating through it.

Comment: How dumb I am! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: As a curious follow up question, what happens when I change the old_list as I am interating through it? If an 'item' is removed from the old_list, what happens in the next iteration?

Comment: @SamTest it will skip items. Try iterating over a list of numbers, print the numbers as you see them and remove all where `n % 3 ==1`. If you are only removing items, in a pinch you can iterate the `reversed()` list, but maybe just better to partition into two lists as you loop.

Comment: Thank you all for help! @ScottHunter if you make it an answer, I would accept yours as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [item for item in old_list if 'keyword' in item]
old_list  = [item for item in old_list if 'keyword' not in item]
```

Comment: Good but you would be better off doing this in a single `for` loop. Not only do you iterate through `old_list` twice but you also search through each word twice for `keyword`.  This is one of those cases where using a `for` loop is better than list comp.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
lst = [{'k1':12},{'k3':77},{'k1':77}]
new_list = []
to_delete = []
for idx,entry in enumerate(lst):
  if 'k1' in entry:
    new_list.append(entry)
    to_delete.append(idx)
to_delete = sorted(to_delete,reverse=True)
for idx in to_delete:
  lst.pop(idx)
print(lst)
print(new_list)
```

output

```
[{'k3': 77}]
[{'k1': 12}, {'k1': 77}]
```